# When transforming a Laplacian from Cartesian to spherical coordinates, why do mixed derivatives vanish?

Tags: real-analysis, partial-derivative, laplacian

I am given a Laplacian in Cartesian coordinates $(x^1, x^2, x^3)$
$$
\Delta = \frac{\partial}{\partial x^i}\frac{\partial}{\partial x^j}\delta^{ij}.
$$
Using the chain rule, I express my Cartesian derivatives in terms of sperical ones
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial x^i} = \frac{\partial r^k}{\partial x^i}\frac{\partial}{\partial r^k},
$$
where my spherical coordinates are $(r^1, r^2, r^3)$ or $(r, \theta, \varphi).$ Using the previous equation, I simply find the second order partial derivatives and hence the Laplacian is
$$
\delta^{ij}\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^i\partial x^j} = 
\delta^{ij}
\left(\frac{\partial^2 }{\partial r^m\partial r^k}
\frac{\partial r^m}{\partial x^j}
\frac{\partial r^k}{\partial x^i} +
\frac{\partial }{\partial r^k}
\frac{\partial^2 r^k}{\partial x^j \partial x^i}\right).
\tag{1}
$$
To actually compute all first and second order derivatives are quite cumbersome, so I thought to ignore all the mixed derivatives, hence only compute those that are in
$$
\sum_{i,j,m,k}
\delta^{ij}\delta^{mk}
\left(\frac{\partial^2 }{\partial r^m\partial r^k}
\frac{\partial r^m}{\partial x^j}
\frac{\partial r^k}{\partial x^i} +
\frac{\partial }{\partial r^k}
\frac{\partial^2 r^k}{\partial x^j \partial x^i}\right).
$$
This resulted in the correct Laplacian
$$
\frac{1}{r^2}\frac{\partial}{\partial r}\left(r^2\frac{\partial }{\partial r}\right) + \frac{1}{r^2\sin\theta}\frac{\partial}{\partial \theta}\left(\sin\theta \frac{\partial}{\partial \theta}\right) + \frac{1}{r^2 \sin^2 \theta}\frac{\partial^2}{\partial \varphi^2}.
$$

My question is: Why can I simply ignore mixed derivatives in (1)?

Comment: An expression of the form $\delta^{mk}X_{mk}Y^{mk}$ makes no sense.

Comment: @J.G. I added a sum symbol to clarify what I meant with the expression.

Comment: @tk . What makes you think that the mixed derivatives do not cancel?

Comment: @KurtG. I didn't say that. I am simply looking for an argument as to why they sum to zero.

Comment: Correct. You did not say that. Sorry. There is probably no way around further cumbersome calculations to arrive at the final form.